# OL6, dynamic color/opacity/transparancy depending on number (percentage) in feature

Tags: dynamic, geojson, opacity, openlayers-6

I'm inspired by this section: https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vector/style.html
especially  the 'dynamic styling'.
Is there an *easy* way to include dynamic styling in my map?

I'm thinking about changing the opacity of a polygon based on the number in the feature.
In my geojson file I've a feature with percentages (`VVD_perc`)

I think I have to change something in my styling-section around this line:
`color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.25)',` but I'm not sure what to change, and where.

I'm thinking of the higher the percentages, the polygon gets less transparent.
so the opacity gets from:

`color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.01)'`by 1 percent 
to
`color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)'` by 100%.

The styling section in the java-script part looks like this:

```
var partijStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.25)',
    }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#319FD3',
    width: 2
  }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: '10px Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#000'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 3
    })
  })
});
```

this is the section where I call for the feature with the percentages. Maybe that is usefull too?

```
var vvdLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonSource,
  //style: partijStyle
  style: function(feature) {
    partijStyle.getText().setText(feature.get(('VVD_perc'))
        );
    return  partijStyle;
 }
});
```

I hope one of you can put me in the right direction. If there is a book or website with an example about this, I'm already happy.

**Thank you Mike for another big help**
I made some other changes too. I hope it helps others.
It appears one cannot make calculations in the `setColor()` part. For that you need to make a `var` as in variabele first.
You can call for that variable between the ().

Below you see a couple of examples. Note I changes the name of the style from `partijStyle` to `vvdStyle`. `vvd_c`stands for `vvd_color`.

```
    //var vvd_c = 'rgba(255, 50, 0, ' + (feature.get('VVD_perc')/100) + ')';
    //var vvd_c = 'rgba(255,'+ (1000/4) +', 0, ' + (feature.get('VVD_perc')/100) + ')';
    //var vvd_c = 'rgba(255,'+ (255-(feature.get('VVD_perc')))  +', 0, ' + (feature.get('VVD_perc')/100) + ')';
    var vvd_c  = 'rgba('+ (feature.get('VVD_perc')+150) +','+ (255-(feature.get('VVD_perc')))  +', 0, ' + (feature.get('VVD_perc')/100) + ')';
    vvdStyle.getFill().setColor(vvd_c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically set some other properties of the style in the same way as you set the text

```
var vvdLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonSource,
  style: function(feature) {
    var perc = feature.get('VVD_perc');
    var color = rgba(100, 100, 100, ' + (perc/100) + ')';
    partijStyle.getFill().setColor(color);
    partijStyle.getText().setText(perc);
    return  partijStyle;
 }
});
```